What happens to a motion under Robert’s Rules of Order if a member resigns from the body mid-deliberation?
In a political organization I was in, during a meeting a member moved a motion but resigned during deliberation. Our parliamentarian was unsure of what the correct course of action would be from there, and we got an additional second and continued deliberation, but for the (rare) chance such a situation arises again, what would be the correct course of action under Robert’s Rules of Order Newly Revised (RONR) 12th edition?

For those unfamiliar, could you mention in your question what RONR stands for?

What did the member resign from exactly? Did they resign from a special office and were still part of the assembly, or did they resign from the assembly alltogether?

@SteveMelnikoff Spelling out acronyms on first use is almost always a good idea. I spelled that out in a minor edit. (Almost always: Everyone knows what NASA, USA, and EU mean. Other than that, spell it out.)

@Philipp resigned from the assembly altogether.

And thanks! I'll keep that in mind for the future for acronyms.

@DavidHammen I'm pretty sure nearly everyone knows what NASA is, but I'm less sure everyone knows what it means.

@MadHatter While I do unfortunately know what Robert's Rules of Order are (aka the royal PITA under which I suffered for a while when I stupidly led a small nonprofit organization), I did not know what RONR was short for; I had to look that up. The point is that it is almost always a good idea to spell out acronyms on first use. So I spelled it out in my minor edit to this question. Regarding NASA: Even British media doesn't spell out that acronym on first use. They are very careful to spell out FBI on first use, but not necessarily NASA.

@DavidHammen I completely agree with you, and I'm sorry if I appeared to suggest otherwise.  I merely note in passing that I don't think "NASA" is a well-understood acronym, for all that it is a well-understood concept.

@MadHatter I suspect most people do not know that the first A in NASA means that NASA not only works on spacecraft (the S in NASA) but also works on research regarding airplanes. The first A in NASA is short for Aeronautics. The final A is short for Administration, which means that the civil servants working at NASA are mostly bureaucrats. (Even JPL strictly is not part of NASA. It is instead a Federally Funded Research & Development Center sponsored by NASA; the workers there are California Institute of Technology employees.)

Itv would be great if a country tag was added. I had too google what robets rules of orders are and which country they apply to, because not even the tag wiki spells out what country is talked about (talk about bad tag wikis...).

I'm not posting this as an answer since it's a personal-skills answer not a procedural one, but I can think of very few cases where it wouldn't be appropriate to have a quick recess while somebody goes and talks to the person who has resigned about whether there's any compromise that would let them stay a member. Robert's rules are good for arriving at the will of the majority, but they aren't a replacement for social skills in keeping an organization from fracturing. If you try and run a local club/social group like the US senate, you won't have a group for very long.

E.g. the goal of Robert's rules is to keep your group cohesive and give you a structured way to resolve disagreements while keeping the group intact. If the rules are leading to people resigning and storming out, they're failing at their goal (or you're relying on them to the exclusion of other things)

@Kaia normally I would agree, but this member had said things during the discussion that would almost certainly warrant an expulsion as soon as possible

The point of having a mover and a second is to ensure at least two members wish for the motion to be considered (§4:12) and to avoid the assembly having to waste time disposing of motions that only one member wishes to introduce. Once the question has been stated by the chair, the motion becomes the property of the assembly (§4:19) and it is up to the assembly to determine whether it wishes to consider it. Once debate has commenced — or, if there is no debate, when any member has voted — this becomes immaterial, and it would be too late to raise a point of order. There is certainly no need to get an additional second, and any points of order raised would not be timely, and should be ruled not well taken. If an assembly no longer wishes to consider the main motion without a direct vote, it can instead adopt a motion to postpone indefinitely (§11).
